# How to adjust row or column height in Tanstack table

Tags: react-table, row-height, tanstack, rowheader

I am using Tanstack table to display dynamic row data which is coming from server.

I have following requirement:

1. I want to fix the row size to fixed height, currently I am facing issue with the row height as it is not constant. Say if there are 50 elements in table, then each row height is perfect which I want. But when there is only 4-5 rows at that time each row height is expanded and tries to fill the whole table height.

I tried to adjust row height by giving custom row height to `<tr>` or `<th>` elements, but beyond one point it is not adjusting.

Requesting you to please help me in finding the root cause and provide the logic to set the custom height as per the user.

Comment: Please provide an example of your code to debug